# php open fdf file in browser

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, fdf

I am working with cakephp. I need to fill up a PDF form for which I have generated the fdf file by getting the code from http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields.

the fdf file is going to generate well but I am unable to open the file in browser. I have put the live PDF form URL in fdf file and use the following header to show the file. But shows the original content of fdf file.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.fdf");
echo file_get_contents($fdf_doc);
```

Please someone help to show the pdf file in browser with the data in fdf file.

Here is the code which I am getting against the above two lines of code

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<< 
/FDF << /Fields [ <</T(First_Name_dyoZTsSYj7AaZZORUqwHRg)/V(m)>><</T(Last_Name_wtE2EKuY4zimhkLHVtbImQ)/V(Jhon)>><</T(Address_iw9xRob*WcfI6Yx1VvF6lA)/V(Steve)>><</T(City_hdYMQhyO73*HEfQYtnWpyg)/V(lahore)>><</T(ZIP_Code_lSOicM9dFoK1WNlOn*BMdg)/V(232323)>><</T(Phone_l3ZSQxhOYwSFuzdOta-WNw)/V(98989898)>><</T(Arrival_Date_Jy6nv5X38KS1lyDYw-*uAQ)/V(01/30/2010)>><</T(Departure_Date_uFmnQc6dxs4jn7s*g32RAA)/V(02/03/2010)>><</T(Number_of_guest_0iHYhUsjJEAoMGsWL9koXA)/V(5)>><</T(Flight_Number_zY9NGizqNvliyJFB0IEmxA)/V(PK-506)>><</T(Time_N18PoY40LFC6LCUUBXb4JA)/V(16:08)>><</T(ADDITIONAL_INFO_0MGHwGHCfZmli5zV6WpKPA)/V(this is for testing for hotel registration)>><</T(file_name)/V(AccommodationRegistration1.pdf)>>] 
/F (http://example.com/pdf_files/AccommodationRegistration1.pdf) /ID [ <2deb20b6495e049130fbca026c4fd1d3>
] >> 
>> 
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R 

>>
%%EOF
```

Comment: I guess your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1390496/1249581.

Comment: pdftk is third party tool, which need to install on server. If we can do it without pdftk that will be better.

Comment: Attention from http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php about `file_get_contents`
Warning

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: Why are you trying to open the FDF file in the browser?  You need to execute some code or program that merges the FDF file and a fillable PDF file, such as the suggested `pdftk`.  The same site has a tutorial: http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields-filled .  Is your intention to download the user's FDF data and manually merge the data with the PDF?

Comment: pdftk is not available on shared hosting, and we need automate process to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11531682/1427338

Comment: Thanks to all for participating to find the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [should generate a pdf out of the fdf](http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields-filled)

helpful articles :

1. [FDF](http://phpbootcamp.com/articles/fdf.htm)
2. [Installing PDFTK on a shared web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531682/1427338)
3. [Adding pdftk to 1and1 shared hosting](http://jheslop.com/2009/11/11/adding-pdftk-to-1and1-shared-hosting/)

Comment: I have create PDF file using PDFTK from FDF file. I did not find any direct solution to show the FDF file in browser. Although I have find come clue while searching on net to show FDF file in browser but it did not work. Thanks to all for participating to find the solution

Answer (score 2):

First try to exit() after echoing the file to prevent CakePHP from adding output to the response.

A cleaner way to do this is using CakeResponse for passing the file through:

```
return $this->response->file($fdf_doc);
```

Comment: This open up the file but do not fill the data. I am trying to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the browser is unable to recognize the content type.
So it thinks it is a plain text and does not know that this is PDF.
You have invalid content type:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.fdf");
```

Try this one:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

Comment: It's not a normal pdf file, it's XFDF data.

Comment: But it seems that browser does not know anything about `application/vnd.fdf`